# Dynamic breadcrumb menu item not invoking action method

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am building a breadcrumb dynamically using selections from dropdown as menu item values, but I am encountering a weird behavior. Following is the code that I am using:

**breadcrumb.xhtml:**

```
<h:form>                        
    <p:breadCrumb id="breadcrumb" model="#{breadcrumbVO.menuModel}">
    </p:breadCrumb>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="select-box" value="#{breadcrumbVO.selectedOption}">
        <p:ajax listener="#{breadcrumbVO.selectionChanged}" update="@form" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="- Select -" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{breadcrumbVO.selectItems}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

**BreadcrumbVO.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

import org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuItem;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuModel;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuElement;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuModel;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BreadcrumbVO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4419933664561553404L;

    private MenuModel menuModel;
    private List<SelectItem> selectItems;

    private String selectedOption; 

    public BreadcrumbVO() {
        menuModel = new DefaultMenuModel();     
        DefaultMenuItem menuItem = new DefaultMenuItem();
        menuItem.setValue("USA");       
        menuItem.setCommand("#{breadcrumbVO.onBredcrumbMenuClick()}");
        menuItem.setUpdate("@form");
        menuModel.addElement(menuItem);                     
        initSelectMenu();    
    }   

    public void selectionChanged() {        
        if(this.selectedOption != ""){
            DefaultMenuItem menuItem = new DefaultMenuItem();
            menuItem.setValue(this.selectedOption);
            menuItem.setCommand("#{breadcrumbVO.onBredcrumbMenuClick()}");
            menuItem.setUpdate("@form");
            this.menuModel.addElement(menuItem);

            refreshSelectMenu();
        }               
    }


    private void refreshSelectMenu() {
        this.selectedOption = null;

        selectItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();  
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("New Item3", "New Item3"));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("New Item4", "New Item4"));      
    }

    private void initSelectMenu(){
        this.selectItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();         
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("New Item1", "New Item1"));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("New Item2", "New Item2"));
    }

    public void onBredcrumbMenuClick(){
        List<MenuElement> menuElements = this.menuModel.getElements();      
        menuElements.remove(menuElements.size()-1);
        initSelectMenu();
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getSelectItems() {
        return selectItems;
    }

    public void setSelectItems(List<SelectItem> selectItems) {
        this.selectItems = selectItems;
    }

    public MenuModel getMenuModel() {
        return menuModel;
    }

    public void setMenuModel(MenuModel menuModel) {
        this.menuModel = menuModel;
    }

    public String getSelectedOption() {
        return selectedOption;
    }

    public void setSelectedOption(String selectedOption) {
        this.selectedOption = selectedOption;
    }              
}
```

The weird behavior I observe is that the `menuItem` which I added to the `menuModel` in the constructor works and correctly invokes the method `onBredcrumbMenuClick` in the bean. But the other menuItems which are added as a result of a user selecting some value from the dropdown, do not invoke this method on click. Even though I am using the same configuration for menu items but they are behaving differently depending upon when they are added in the `menuModel`.

Explanations are appreciated.